# How to add minor tick marks in MS Chart in C# Windows Form?

Tags: c#

How to add minor tick marks in MS Chart in Windows Form.

I am using below code but minor tick marks are not showing up.

```
 chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorTickMark.Enabled = true;
 chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = 1;
 chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
 chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorTickMark.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorTickMark.Interval = 2;
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The way you turn on `MinorTickMarks` as such is **fine**.

**But** if you want to use different `IntervalTypes` you need to understand the numeric values behind the types.

Internally all values, both x- and y-values are defined and stored as `doubles`.

If you declare some of them to be `DateTimes` they get converted to `double` (and when necessary back to `DateTime`) by the conversion functions: [`double.ToOADate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tooadate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_ToOADate)  (and [`FromOADate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.fromoadate?view=netframework-4.8)).

Let's have a look at the values resulting for **one second**:

```
DateTime dt0 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dt1 = dt0 .AddSeconds(1);

double d0 = dt0.ToOADate();
double d1 = dt1.ToOADate();

double dd = d1 - d0;

Console.WriteLine(d0 + " .. " +  d1 + "  => "  + dd);
```

Output:

> 43612,4597045023 .. 43612,4597160764  => 1,15740695036948E-05

So, with such a tiny value an `Interval` of `1`, as in your code, just won't happen within the chart. Best use a different type, like `DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds` with an suitable `Interval`, like `500`..!